# php time till specific date and time

Tags: php, time, strtotime

This is my current code:

```
$nm = strtotime('next monday 19:30');
$nt = strtotime('next wednesday 19:30');
$ns = strtotime('next Saturday 09:00');
```

It kind of works but let's say it is wednesday it won't tell me something like X hours, it will tell me 1 week X hours.

How do I fix this?

You can see the live demo here: http://www.forumalliance.x10.mx/troll.php

Comment: Have a look at `date_diff`

Answer (score 0):

To calculate `weeks` and `hours` first get time interval between `now` and `desired time`. Then divide the `interval` by seven days equivalent seconds to get week no and `mod` to get rest hours. Example:

```
$nm = strtotime('next monday 19:30');
$interval = $nm - time();
$week = floor($interval / (7 * 24 * 60 * 60));
$hour = floor(($interval % (7 * 24 * 60 * 60)) / 3600);

echo $week . ' week ' . $hour . ' hour(s)';
```

Comment: That gives me 0 weeks and 120 hours :S

Comment: Because 1 week is 168 hours but interval is 120 hours. so it shows 0 week.

Answer (score 0):

### This got what I needed.

```
$day = date('l');
$hour = date('H');
$min = date('i');


if ($hour <= 19 and $min < 30 and $day == "Monday") {
    $nm = strtotime('this monday 19:30');
}else{
    $nm = strtotime('next monday 19:30');
}

if ($hour <= 19 and $min < 30 and $day == "Wednesday") {
    $nt = strtotime('this wednesday 19:30');
}else{
    $nt = strtotime('next wednesday 19:30');
}

if ($hour <= 09 and $min < 00 and $day == "Saturday") {
    $ns = strtotime('this saturday 09:00');
}else{
    $ns = strtotime('next saturday 09:00');
}
```